# MySQL Multiple JOINS on the same cell

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm pretty new to SQL. I've been googling for hours and I'm stuck with this problem:

I have a table `games` with following keys:

```
gameID, homeTeamID, awayTeamID
```

And a table `teams` with following keys:

```
teamID, teamName, teamTLC
```

Now I want to query a game along with the team names and team tlcs. I guess the query might look something like this:

```
SELECT games.id, teams.name
  FROM games
  WHERE games.homeTeamID = 34 OR games.awayTeamID = 34
    INNER JOIN teams AS homeTeam
      ON leagueGame.homeTeamID = homeTeam.teamID
    INNER JOIN teams AS awayTeam
      ON leagueGame.awayTeamID = awayTeam.teamID
```

But I'm pretty sure that this code is completely wrong. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not that far... :

- the `WHERE` clause comes after the `FROM ... JOIN` part
- as you are querying for *a game*, you want to filter on `gameID` rather than on  teams
- you have no table alias called `teams` ; you need to use the table aliases that you defined in the `JOIN`s.

Try :

```
SELECT games.id, homeTeam.name AS homeTeamName, awayTeam.name AS awayTeamName
FROM games
INNER JOIN teams AS homeTeam
      ON leagueGame.homeTeamID = homeTeam.teamID
INNER JOIN teams AS awayTeam
      ON leagueGame.awayTeamID = awayTeam.teamID
WHERE games.gameID = ?
```

NB : if you need `teamTLC` as well, you can access it using table aliases `awayTeam` and `homeTeam`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to change the order.  first you need to have all your data, then your criteria.

```
SELECT
  games.id,
  teams.name
FROM
  games
INNER JOIN teams as homeTeam ON leagueGame.homeTeamID = homeTeam.teamID
INNER JOIN teams as awayTeam ON leagueGame.awayTeamID = awayTeam.teamID
WHERE
  games.homeTeamID = 34
  OR games.awayTeamID = 34
```